# Windows OS reinstall on Mirrored disks. Old disks are "pack is not online"

Tags: windows, software-raid

I was having issues with a Windows Server 2012 system, and decided to re-do it.  It had two each of SSD and HDD with both being mirrored sets.

After a fresh install on one SSD, Showing up in "Disk Management" are three “Missing” Dynamic disks. When I try to “remove” one of them, it tells me “The pack is not online.”

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Windows OS can't recognize the partition on the dynamic disk. You can try to restore your partition using 3rd party tools. https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/dynamic-disk-invalid.html

Also, if the data is not so useful (or you have backups), just clean the drive. Open CMD as Administrator, run diskpart; list disk; select disk x; clean.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, however, I can't see the drives, as they are "missing".  I can't clean them if I can't see them.  
In actuality, I reformatted one, and broke the other set.  I don't know how the freshly installed OS knows about disks that it has never seen.

Comment: If your server comes with IPMA (iDrac, ILO), take a look at drives pane, are there any warnings or something similar?

Comment: It doesn't have any of those things, just the Windows software mirroring.